# Android OnTouch action up not doesn't fire with sweeping

Tags: java, android, swipe, ontouchlistener

I have set an OnTouchListener on a imageview in my gridview, so everytime it's clicked ACTION DOWN fires and i change the background of the image of a clicked version of it, so it emulates a click and on ACTION UP i return the old

Everything works fine when I click it but when i slide it slightly out of bounds the UP event doesn't happen and the image stays the same. That seems logical to me since I am not releasing the touch but I am sliding it outside of the imageview. I tried to limit the background change to happen only if the click is inside the bounds of the view, but nothing worked, this is my touch listener event :

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(mContext) {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    // Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + imageView.toString());
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                       ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.test01);
                       Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + "Action down Inside");

                        //imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
                        Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + "Action down");
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
                        Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + "Action up");
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

and this is another version in which i tried something else :

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(mContext) {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    // Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + imageView.toString());
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.i("IMAGE", "xC: " + (int)motionEvent.getX() + "   yC:" + (int)motionEvent.getX());
                        if(isViewContains(view, (int)motionEvent.getX(), (int)motionEvent.getY())) {
                            ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.test01);
                            Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + "Action down Inside");
                        }
                        //imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
                        Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + "Action down");
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
                        Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + "Action up");
                        return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

this is the function that I am using

```
private boolean isViewContains(View view, int rx, int ry) {
        int[] l = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(l);
        Rect rect = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
        Log.i("IMAGE", "x: " + rx + "  y:" + ry);
        if(rect.contains(view.getLeft()+ rx, view.getTop() + ry)) {
                Log.i("IMAGE", "contains");
        }
        return rect.contains(view.getLeft()+ rx, view.getTop() + ry);
}
```

Do you have any hints or suggestions ? What I want to is no matter what I do swipe or click the original image to return.

Comment: Try MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL

Comment: how can I give you rep for this?

Comment: i post this as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL** in **onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)**